# Specifying center and zoom for ol.View

Tags: javascript, openlayers, zoom, center

Is it a must to specifiy center and zoom when you declare ol.View?
Because it still works when I pass in the extent value to fit function.
Here's the example.

This is my map variable.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    interactions: interactions,
    controls: [],
    layers: [vWorldBase, vWorldGray, vWorldSatellate],
    // layers: [layer],
    target: 'map',
    view: view,
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
});
```

Here are my interactions and layers

```
var interactions = ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate: false, dragPan: false, rotate: false }).extend([new ol.interaction.DragPan({ kinetic: null })]);
var vWorld_attribution = new ol.Attribution({
    html: '<a target="_blank" href="http://map.vworld.kr/" '
        + 'style="float: left; width: 353px; height: 29px; cursor: pointer; background-image: url(//map.vworld.kr/images/maps/logo_openplatform.png); background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat; " '
        + 'title="VWorld 지도로 보시려면 클릭하세요."></a>'
        + ''
});

var vWorldBase = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: [vWorld_attribution],
        crossOrigin: "anonymous",
        url: '//xdworld.vworld.kr:8080/2d/Base/service/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    }),
    // visible: false
});

var vWorldGray = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: [vWorld_attribution],
        crossOrigin: "anonymous",
        url: '//xdworld.vworld.kr:8080/2d/gray/service/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    }),
    visible: false
});

var flag = (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident') > 0 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge/') > 0) ? true : false;

if (flag) {
    //url 변경
    var url = '//xdworld.vworld.kr:8080/2d/Base/service/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    vWorldGray.getSource().setUrl(url);
    //타일 회색적용
    vWorldGray.on('postcompose', function (evt) {
        setGrayCtx(evt.context)
    });
}

var vWorldSatellate = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: [vWorld_attribution],
        crossOrigin: "anonymous",
        url: '//xdworld.vworld.kr:8080/2d/Satellite/service/'
            + '{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg'
    }),
    visible: false
});
```

Here's the view variable

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:5179', "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=127.5 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=2000000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs");
ol.proj.setProj4(proj4);

var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:5179');

var view = new ol.View({
    projection: projection,
    // center: [955111.84183247, 1950405.9777143092],
    // zoom: 13,
    // minZoom: 7,
    // maxZoom: 19
});
```

And I passed in the extent to fit function like this

```
view.fit([933077.7209393228, 1938096.5596410807, 976424.9039833639, 1959770.1511631014]);
```

As you can see I commented out all except projection and yet the map is rendered.
So when you use fit function to render the map you don't have to have the center and zoom setting in your ol view?

Comment: Correct, `fit()` calculates and sets the `center` and `resolution` needed to fit the extent.